# List of dictionaries in a Scrollview using KivyMD python

Tags: python, dictionary, listview, kivy, scrollview

Given a list containing a unspecified number of dictionaries,

```
[ 
{Key11: Value11, Key21: Value21, Key31: Value31, Key41: Value41, Key51: Value51},
{Key12: Value12, Key22: Value22, Key32: Value32, Key42: Value42, Key52: Value52},
{Key13: Value13, Key23: Value23, Key33: Value33, Key43: Value43, Key53: Value53},
.
.
.
{Key1n: Value1n, Key2n: Value2n, Key3n: Value3n, Key4n: Value4n, Key5n: Value5n}
]
```

What would be the best way to represent them in Kivy ScrollView as follow

[image]

The only option I see so far is to change all the dictionary into list and then use MDlist. But that gets quickly messy.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[RecycleView](https://kivy.org/doc/master/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) is probably what you want.